# Application triggering an AMD discrete card on a Windows laptop

Tags: opengl, driver, amd-gpu

I am developing a 3D application that requires the use of a high-end card, such as the ones developed by NVidia or AMD. Now, on laptops, the issue is to get the application detected as such. For NVidia, the documentation states if an application export the symbol `NvOptimusEnablement`, then the NVidia discrete card will be chosen by default. Is there anything equivalent for the AMD system?

I couldn't find anything in the documentation for the AMD Muxless Switchable Graphics Technology.

Comment: I hope you don't mind, but I removed the [laptop] tag; it's been wiped out from Stack Overflow before, since users just assume that [laptop] hardware questions are on-topic because the tag exists.

Comment: `AmdPowerXpressRequestHighPerformance` but I can't find an authoritative source